# In C, what is the difference between comma and semicolon for statements that are discarded

Tags: c, syntax, conventions

I ask because as I was perusing the source code for grep, I noticed that it uses an element of C syntax, the comma, in a way that I'm not used to seeing it, for example:

```
r = links[depth], l = r->llink, t = l->rlink;
rl = t->rlink, lr = t->llink;
t->llink = l, l->rlink = lr, t->rlink = r, r->llink = rl;
```

I researched the usage, and found:

> When used as an operator, the comma operator uses the following syntax:
>
> `expr1, expr2`
>
> The left operand expr1 is evaluated as a void expression (i.e. it is ignored if not contain side effects), then expr2 is evaluated to give the result and type of the comma expression. So, the result is just expr2.

(source: http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/opers.html#comma)

So if the comma operator is really "the same" as a semicolon (assuming, of course, that we don't need to use the return value of the expression), in that writing

```
f(2); g(3);
```

is functionally equivalent to writing

```
f(2), g(3);
```

or even

```
f(2), g(2),
```

why do we use the semicolon instead? Why didn't the grep authors just follow convention and use semicolons instead of commas, since C ignores whitespace so newlines are irrelevant??

Very puzzling.

Comment: Probably just stylistically to create a sort of grouping. I don't think there's a functional difference.

Comment: Unless you can get the authors of the code to answer this authoritatively, I don't think you'll be able to get a true answer, just our opinions. Anyway, I agree with @AlexisKing above—this seems to just be a logical grouping of related assignments.

Comment: just as a comment, i think saying the comma operator is really "the same" as the semicolon is a stretch of "the same" no matter how you slice it. the semicolon is a statement terminator in C. the comma is a statement combinator. it may in certain cases have the same results, sure, but it is certainly not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code shown, the commas could be replaced with semi-colons and there'd be no difference in the way the code worked.  It is probably just a way to emphasize how closely related the three operations are.

There are times, though, when the difference is important. For example:

```
if (links[depth] != 0)
    r = links[depth], l = r->llink, t = l->rlink;
```

vs:

```
if (links[depth] != 0)
    r = links[depth]; l = r->llink; t = l->rlink;
```

Despite the way it's written, the compiler sees:

```
if (links[depth] != 0)
    r = links[depth];
l = r->llink;
t = l->rlink;
```

which is not the same thing at all.  It also matters in the loop initialization and reinitialization sections of a `for` loop:

```
int i, j;
…
for (i = 0, j = max; i < j; i++, j--)
```

You can't replace those commas with semicolons.

Comment: i think you should emphasize the for loop example in your answer; as it is actually the epitome of why the comma operator is a nice-to-have (and one of the reasons i rather miss it in C#)... it's a way of grouping a couple of expressions together when you need to do a couple of things at the same time, but it doesn't really warrant (and actually may make things less clear to be) writing out a bigger block of code elsewhere.